# When should one use "FOR" in Present perfect continuous and when shouldn't

Tags: perfect-continuous

Two examples:

1. it has been raining **for** several days
2. It has been raining all week

Why does the first one has **for** and the second doesn't? Is there a rule where one should use **for** or shouldn't?

Comment: This is unrelated to present perfect continuous: "it rains for several days" / "it rains all week" - you can replace any tense you want and it will still take that form. These "all week/day/etc." are fixed expressions and they are another way of saying "for the whole week/day/etc"

Answer (score -1):

I think this is as much a stylistic question, as it is about tenses.  Having been asked the question, "For how long did it rain", one could answer:

"It rained for several days"

"It rained for the first half of the week"

"It rained for the entire week"

"It rained for all of the week"

However, "It rained all week" is both sufficient and efficient.  In short, the second does not contain 'for', because the writer probably decided it was unnecessary and superfluous.

Comment: One could even ask "_How long did it rain?_", without for.

Comment: Precisely, Farid.

Answer (score -1):

We do not use "for" + all: all day, all week, all morning, all the time

but we can use "for" with: "for all time", "for all eternity"